# Using value of a property as property name in anonymous object

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to use the value of a property as a value of a anonymous object, within a `.Select(...)` statement?

I get a flat list of items back from the server, which I group by on of the properties. 
The object that get's returned from the database looks like:

```
public class Locale
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string ParentKey { get; set; }
}
```

A simple EF query brings back all the items from the database:

```
var locales = await _context.Locales.ToListAsync();
```

which I then group:

```
var result = locales.GroupBy(x => x.ParentKey).Where(x => null != x.Key);
```

I would then like to use the Key, for example "_title", as the property name in an anonymous object. The reason for this is, I need to pass data to a 3rd party Angular component, and they are expecting the return property be the value of the "key" and property's value, the Value.

My attempt so far, but this does not work:

```
var output = result.SelectMany(x => new {
    lang = x.Key,
    data = x.SelectMany(p => new {
        p.Key = p.Value
    })
});
```

Reason being that the anonymous method needs a defined property name. 
I was hoping to get by without a convoluted reflection / JObject route, but it seems that's the only way.

Comment: would projecting it as a dictionary be good an option? Are all `Key` properties with the same `ParentKey` identical?

Comment: unfortunately not, they need it in { lang: "en", data: { _title: "my awesome title" } }, where _title can actually be any key defined by the user. as long as it's in this format. yes, all parentkey is identical. the grouping works fine, so i can retrieve the first part of the requirement find [ { lang: "en" }, { lang: "fr" } ], it's the dynamic data: {} that i'm struggling with. i've never tried to do this from C# without reflection :$

Comment: Is the output format supposed to be a json format?

Comment: nevermind, i'm stupid. should give up on development. projection to dictionary will definitely work as the JSON serialization uses the dictionary's key/value part to build the json string. thanks @GiladGreen. i'm retiring from dev :D

Comment: Haha :) glad it was a good solution :) That is why I verified the JSON

Comment: BTW - I'd to the `ToListAsync` after the `Where` and `Grouping` but before projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could project each grouping to a dictionary. Then you serialize it and get desired output:

```
var output = locales.Where(x => x.ParentKey != null)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.ParentKey)                                
                    .Select(x => new {
                        lang = x.Key,
                        data = x.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value)
                    });

var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
```

For example data:

```
var locales = new List<Locale> {
    new Locale { LanguageId = 1, Key = "a", Value = "1", ParentKey = "1" },
    new Locale { LanguageId = 2, Key = "b", Value = "2", ParentKey = "2" },
    new Locale { LanguageId = 3, Key = "c", Value = "3", ParentKey = "2" },
};
```

yields:

```
[{"lang":"1","data":{"a":"1"}},
 {"lang":"2","data":{"b":"2","c":"3"}}]
```